# function done in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Actually I am reading some codes in Nodejs, but I cannot get what it means because some common use of `function` that I don't quite understand. Can someone tell me what the `function(done)` means? It is a callback or something? in the js file I can't see the definition of `done`. Thanks

Andes

```
var getRedisUri = exports.getRedisUri = function (done) {
if (process.env.CLUSTER_CONFIG_URI) {
    return done(null, process.env.CLUSTER_CONFIG_URI);
}
//redis uri
Fs.readFile(
    '/opt/redis_uri',
    {encoding: 'utf8'},
    function (err, redis_uri_data) {
        if (err) {return done(err);}

        var redis_uri = redis_uri_data.toString();


        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
            process.env.VM_DOMAIN &&
            (redis_uri.indexOf('localhost') !== -1 || redis_uri.indexOf('127.0.0.1') !== -1)) {
            redis_uri = redis_uri.replace('localhost', process.env.VM_DOMAIN);
            redis_uri = redis_uri.replace('127.0.0.1', process.env.VM_DOMAIN);
        }

        done(null, redis_uri);
    });
};
```

Comment: It's just a standard Node.js callback. Do you know how callbacks work?

Comment: Hi,turrle. I can understand the callback, but I just cannot find out where is the done function. How can I find it? In IDE I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

That line is just the start of a function definition. `function(done)` just means that when this function is called, it should be called with one argument, and during the execution of the function, that argument will be referred to as `done`.

More specifically, I think it has to do with middleware (are you using express.js here?). If you have a bunch of middleware functions in express, the express router will call those functions for you, and pass in a function as an argument which, when called, passes the request to the next middleware function. It seems like that's what's happening here, as `done` gets called at the end of the function.

Node.js has stuff like this because it's all asynchronous, so you can't use `return` statements for much.

Comment: thank you Raphael. I don't think I have express.js, because I don't have this js lib in my lib. what else it may be? I cannot jump to the `done` var in my IDE, it just show this `done` is a var. no more hints.

Comment: It might not be obvious just from reading the code. You should read the redis documentation.